# Updating records in table with ID from another table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Appreciate any help in advance!

I have a DB with two tables, var table and val table.

### var table

varid
image
vartype

### val table

valid
sig
winner
varid

The tables have a 1 to many relationship, meaning there are many val's per var.

Now with that established, I have a form that asks for the input to populate that database.

1. The user can add multiple vals in one go - basically I have the form setup using ajax so when the user completes the fields, it posts to my vale table and then refreshes the content (not the page) using ajax/jquery so the user can enter another val/record.
2. Once the user has entered all of their vals, the user should add the var record.  When that var posts to the var table, an varid is automatically assigned and should be associated with the last X number of vals the user entered.

For example

### var table

varid | image | vartype 
1 | test.jpg | button

### val table

valid | sig | winner | varid
1 | true |  true | 1
2 | false | true | 1
3 | true | true | 1

Anyway, I need help understanding the procedure or theory behind this... In my mind, it goes something like this.

1. My ajax should have a counter to count how many vals the user enters.
2. Within the php file that the val form is submitted to, should enter the data and then store the id of the record just entered in an array - pass it back to the page.  each time a record is added, the valid will be stored
3. when the user is finished entering vals, it will enter the var - when the php file (separate from val file) is called, it will:
    **a.** insert the var 
    **b.** grab the id of the var
    **c.** update the records in the val table based on array of ids with the var id

does this sound right or am I totally in space somewhere?

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do this for all your elements : $("#secondtablefieldid").val($("#firsttablefieldid").val());

Comment: the id's are set on the DB level...not sure how that is going to help me...or maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) var and fill it with an array of all the 'valid' using MySQLS [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html) function.

Then when making the 'var' table insert you can simply update the 'val' table rows that match the 'valid''s stored in the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) var.

Don't forget to clear the [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) var once that's finished.

Comment: Maybe this will help you get into the right direction a little http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/10g-bct

Comment: thanks for taking the time out to write it all out for me.  I think that is exactly what I am looking at, but with that said, I want to try and get this on my own...I've written some code, to get me where I need to be, but when I try and echo my session variable it returns "array".  any thoughts on where I am going wrong? $valuearray=array();
$_SESSION['valueid']=$valuearray;

$valid=mysqli_insert_id($con);

array_push($_SESSION['valueid'], $valid);

Comment: **insert.php**
$valueidd = mysqli_insert_id($con);
$_SESSION['vals'][] = $valueidd;


**forminput.php**
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['vals'])) 
{
$_SESSION['vals'] = array();
}

When I attempt to echo the array, it always echos the first array element [0], as if each time i submit my form it overwrites the previous array value...so the array/session variable is not stacking, rather just updating/overwriting.  ANy thoughts?

Comment: First of all the reason when you simply try to echo $_SESSION['valueid'] returns array() is because it is an array(). Try using [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) or [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) on the array and take a look at what it returns.